# Best way to use WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We have a large PHP application that exposes an API with OAuth2 security. Up to now, the API has only been used internally, however several customers need to consume it. We are reluctant to give them credentials and thought of WSO2 API Manager as an intermediate solution to provide them with a limited version of the API that only contains the methods required by customers.

What we need to do is to APIM to automatically generate a token in our API and pass it along in all the requests received from external customers.

Any guidance on how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write an OAuth2 mediator to get this done. Basically this mediator is used to get an access token before calling the backend. A sample implementation can be found in https://github.com/npamudika/wso2-oauth-mediator

Comment: Thank you. I've compiled the project with Maven, added the OAuth mediator JAR to the server and configured the JSON file with our API credentials. 
Configured the WSO2 API with an out flow mediation policy but it doesn't seem to be working. Is there anything missing in the WSO2 API configuration?

Comment: you need to add these configuration to in-flow mediation policy as it should be passed to back-end.

Comment: @VithursaM when setting the mediation policy as in-flow I get this error as I call the API via cURL:

```<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager"><am:code>0</am:code><am:type>Status report</am:type><am:message>Runtime Error</am:message><am:description>Error while building message. Error while building Passthrough stream</am:description></am:fault>```


when using out-flow I get:
```{"statusCode":401}```